# Creating a Custom Single Post Template For Custom Post Type Based On Category

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

Trying to create multiple, single custom templates, for a custom post type, based on the custom port type's custom taxonomy.

For example: when a post has a certain category, it will use a different template, rather than the default single-custom-post-type-name.php

This is what I have tried so far. But it does not seem to be working. And I assuming it is because I am trying this on a CPT.

```
add_filter('single_template', create_function(
'$the_template',
'foreach( (array) get_the_category() as $cat ) {
    if ( file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php") )
    return TEMPLATEPATH . "/single-{$cat->slug}.php"; }
return $the_template;' )
```

);

Answer (score 0):

exaple loop in the myposttype-single.php (slug of your posttype) file:

```
while (have_posts()) : the_post();

    $category = get_the_category();
    $firstCategory = $category[0]->cat_name;

    if ( $firstCategory === 'yourcategoryname' ){
        get_template_part( 'partials/myposttype', 'specialcat' );
    } else {
        get_template_part( 'partials/myposttype', 'default' );
    }

endwhile;
```

- than create a folder called "partials" in your theme folder.
- in this folder you create two files called "myposttype-specialcat.php" and "myposttype-default.php". Add the same code into this file like in a normal template.. header, loop, footer etc..

if the first categoryname of that post will be "yourcategoryname" it will take the special template and not the default one.